# How to install r10k without network?

Tags: rubygems, puppet

I'm using Puppet and I would like to use r10k. I have no internet on my server. and I would like to install r10k.

I downloaded the tar.gz and I would like to install it. is there anyway to do that ?

Comment: Why not download the gems locally and install it?

Comment: If you have no internet on the server then you cannot use r10k anyway since it requires a network connection for the git, hg, and puppet forge commands.

Comment: @MattSchuchard He states his system is not connected to the internet, not that it is not connected to a git and everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Download the gem, e.g. at [rubygems.org](https://rubygems.org/gems/r10k/versions/2.3.0). Transfer it to your offline system.

There use:

```
 gem install --force --local *.gem
```

to install the gem manually. For possible dependencies of r10k, you need to install those as well like this.

Answer (score -1):

If you have tar.gz file and want to install it by puppet then you can use "Exec" and mention the proper command or sequence of commands.

Comment: This is not what he is asking.